# What is the title of SciFi anthology with a short story about the singers at the end of time?

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The anthology cover shows a woman and man (lower left) and some barrel-chested natives (upper right).

While listening to the natives sing, the anthropologists are transported to the far future where the air is very thin (hence the barrel chests).

Comment: Dancers at the End of Time, I could answer... no clue as to this one, which means it was probably published after 1975.

Comment: When did you read this?

Comment: Most likely between 1960 and 1967.